# Crontab commands not executed correctly

Tags: bash, cron

I asked for some help with `speedtest-cli` a few days ago and now I need help with the following:

I made this crontab:

```
0 * * * * (date +"%A, %d.%m.%Y %X Uhr" >> /home/pi/speedtest/speed.txt; /usr/bin/speedtest-cli --server 3645 --simple >> /home/pi/speedtest/speed.txt; echo "\n" >> /home/pi/speedtest/speed.txt)
10 * * * * (speedtest-cli --server 3645 --share; grep -Po 'Share results: \K.*' >> /home/pi/speedtest/latest.txt)
```

(look here to see it better formatted: https://hastebin.com/holugehuvo.js)

I'll explain, what I want to do with it: So the first command should print the current date and time in my region format into a text file. The output of `speedtest-cli --server 3645 --simple` should be appended to the same file and after that should be a new line so that I can see the next output (output one hour later) correctly formatted.

An output of the command `speedtest-cli --server 3645 --simple` would be something like that:

```
Ping: xx.xx ms
Download: 53.09 Mbit/s
Upload: 7.92 Mbit/s
```

This should be repeated every hour.

And the second cron should grep the `http://` address returned by the command and print that into a file called latest.txt.

An example output for `speedtest-cli --server 3645 --share` would be sth like that:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Provider (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Citycom Telekommunikation GmbH (Graz) [xx.xx km]: xx.xxx ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 52.88 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: 7.62 Mbit/s
Share results: http://www.speedtest.net/result/7799311524.png
```

I just need that `http://` address because I want to read that in PHP and display this png on my local web page so that I know what was my last speed test.

Both commands should run once per hour, I used a little offset so that the speed is not influenced by the other speedtest made in the first command.

I need both outputs because I want to monitor my last speeds AND have that image accessible with PHP.

I know that this was/is a long question, but I want to give you many details so that it's easier to understand what I wanted to do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to escape the `%`

Comment: You mean with a \ in front of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points of improvement here:

1. **Usage of `%`:**

   You have to escape it and write it as `\%`

   > The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a `%` character, will be executed by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in the `SHELL` variable
   >      of the cronfile.  A `%` character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first `%` will be sent to the command as standard input.
   >
   > **<sub>source: `man 5 crontab`</sub>**
2. **Compound commands**

   You write multiple commands in a single crontab command as

   ```
   ( command1; command2 ) >> /path/to/output
   ```

   While this works, it must be mentioned that this will spawn a sub-shell and is a bit an overkill. You might consider not to do so using:

   ```
   { command1; command2; } >> /path/to/output
   ```

   or if you do not want `command2` to execute if `command1` failed, you could do:

   ```
   command1 && command2 >> /path/to/output
   ```
3. **Usage of pipe:** Your second command should use a pipe (`|`)

   ```
   speedtest-cli --server 3645 --share | grep -Po 'Share results: \K.*' >> /home/pi/speedtest/latest.txt
   ```

Comment: 1. Thanks for this short, but helpful answer.
2. Do I also need to change other things or do you think, it'll work as it is?

Comment: @user316860 I have updated the text with some more information.

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: Are pipes working in cron as they would in the standard bash? This is my last question. @kvantour

Comment: @user316860 yes. You might also consider to write all your commands in a single shell-script and just execute that one script.